# Unable to stop thread execution onPause and resume exectuion onResume

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

I am relatively new to coding. I am developing a pingpong game with multiple modes like easy,hard etc. I have created a customView called gameboard as follows-

```
    class GameBoard : View {
    @Volatile var gameOn = false
    //several member variables
    
    fun start(){
                gameOn = true
                GameThread().start()
            }
    
    fun stop(){
                gameOn = false
            }
    
    inner class GameThread : Thread()
        {
            override fun run()
            {  
               while (gameOn) {
               //do some processes 
               if (ballOutsideRange) {
                   gameOn = false
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

I have a main activity as follows -

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mGameBoard:GameBoard
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_MainActivity)

        this.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
        mGameBoard = GameBoard(this.applicationContext)
        mGameBoard.setMode("easy")

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        mGameBoard.gameOn = true
        super.onResume()
        //mGameBoard.start()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        mGameBoard.gameOn = false
        super.onPause()
       

    }
}
```

When the main activity goes to the background, the game continues. I am expecting the game to stop because I set the gameOn variable to false. I also am calling the thread start() from the customView gameboard onSizeChanged as follows. I had to call the function start() from there because this is where I am getting the correct height and width of the customView-

```
  override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        mWidth = width
        mHeight = height
        cxBall = (Random.nextInt(1, mWidth)).toFloat()
        cyBall = (mHeight/6).toFloat()
        cxPaddle = (width/2 - PADDLE_WIDTH/2).toFloat()
        paintScoreText.textSize = height / 20f
        paintHighScoreText.textSize = height / 20f


        start()


    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't quite make sense. Did you define `gameOn` again in `MainActivity`?

Comment: Sorry, I added gameOn as a global variable and it worked. I need to keep it as class member. So the updated code looks like this -        override fun onResume() {
        mGameBoard.gameOn = true
        super.onResume()
        //mGameBoard.start()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        mGameBoard.gameOn = false
        super.onPause()
       

    }

Comment: I'd expect that to work.